# java application doesn't run on another computer

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

hello guys i just want to ask if anyone can point out the problem to me.

so like the title stated, my problem is i clean and build my java application, and my java application has a database that is connected to mysql.

i tried placing the .sql file to the dist folder where the jar file is located, then transferred it to another computer and run it there but it didnt run and said no connection is established between the application and the database.

i hope i can get an answer or a pointers perhaps because im just new in developing java applications.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can the other computer connect to your mysql database? This sounds like a "how do I connect to a database" question.

Comment: well the other computer has a mysql too but im not sure if its my connection codes or what..

Answer (score 1):

"https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html" i guess u need to add mysql driver properly

Comment: well the jar file and its sub directory after i clean and build the application contains the jconnector already still figuring out why it says connection cannot be established

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the other computer can connect to your mysql database if yes next confirm that while connecting from your machine you have used proper ip and port number where your mysql database is running in your connection object.

Comment: about that proper ip and port where can i see those stuff?

Comment: Then place where you are setting the new machines IP address or where you set your local host earlier when the mysql server was in your own machine.Kindly check it.I guess that is not set

Comment: im not sure with that but ill try it out hopefully it works.

Comment: Can u share ur work set structure so that I can tell u exactly where is it.